# How to add vertical gutter to Element components?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, element-ui

All the examples in Element docs show components nicely spaced one from each other.

When taking a basic example such as

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app"
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/element-ui/lib/index.js"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/element-ui/lib/theme-chalk/index.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="app">
  <el-row :gutter="20">
    <el-col :span="4">
      <el-input></el-input>
    </el-col>
    <el-col :span="4">
      <el-input></el-input>
    </el-col>
  </el-row>
  <el-row :gutter="20">
    <el-col :span="4">
      <el-input></el-input>
    </el-col>
    <el-col :span="4">
      <el-input></el-input>
    </el-col>
  </el-row>
</div>
```

you see that the two rows of `<el-input>` are glued one to each other.

`:gutter` is a solution to space columns horizontally. **What is the correct approach to space the rows vertically?** (see for instance [this example](https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/input#input-with-icon) where the two rows are spaced)

Comment: How did you resolved the issue?

Comment: @InfoStatus: I switched to Quasar :) (https://quasar.dev/)

Answer (score -2):

Just write css, margin or padding because **:gutter** just use for Margin left and right.